# C# WPF Hiding specific items within a <Menu>

Tags: c#, menu, menuitem

I've got a `<menu>` on my window which contains `<TextBlock>`, `<Separator>` and `<MenuItem>` within it and I need to loop through everything, only get the `<MenuItem>`, check its text value and hide it if it doesn't match text in my `TextBox`.

I've got the below code but it breaks when setting the `item.Visibility` as `object does not contain a definition for 'Visibility'...`:

```
    private void ItemsSearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(object item in ItemsMenu.Items)
        {
            Type type = item.GetType();
            if(type.Equals(typeof(MenuItem)))
            {
                var menuItemText_split = item.ToString().Split(' ', 1); 
                if (menuItemText_split[1].StartsWith(ItemsSearchBox.Text)) 
                { 
                    item.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
                }
            }
        }  
    }
```

I am doing the `.Split()` on the text due to it having a number displayed on the UI and I need to check the text after it. Luckily there is a space between the text I am after and the number, e.g. "1. TextIamAfter".

How can I make it so the `item` at the `item.Visibility...` part doesn't error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

WPF is designed to support DataBinding.  In your example, I suggest making your menu "data-driven".  Rather than attempt to manipulate the menu items directly, you can bind the "items" of a menu to a list and your menu will automatically update if you modify that list.  See [How to correctly bind menu items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246718/how-to-correctly-bind-menu-items) for an example.